# Are they any tutorial of how to use GWT with PureMVC framework?

Tags: gwt, puremvc

I tried to google and found nothing.

Is there any website which show how to implement GWT with PureMVC?

Comment: Are you referring to this http://code.google.com/p/purevmc4gwt/ or are you asking for rest of the world to google it for you?

Comment: There is no pure MVC.. ..GWT have MVP pattern.

Comment: I mean how to apply PureMVC(http://puremvc.org/) with GWT.
I'm working on GWT web development project on Eclipse and I'm interested to apply PureMVC to my GWT project but I don't see any example code after googling it.

Comment: code.google.com/p/purevmc4gwt is one attempt at it.. take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by referring to http://code.google.com/p/purevmc4gwt/ . The project is abandoned with no activity since 2008. There has been massive changes in GWT since and ***GWT has moved towards a MVP approach to accommodate web-centric optimization***. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture

PureMVC also has several attempts with javascript ports. The last one seems to have vanished http://puremvc.org/content/view/156/1/

If you have tried any puremvc javacript ports. You can write JSNI wrappers and utilize them. It will be quite a challenge :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294768/Exploring-another-MVC-variant-PureMVC

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mvc/

GWT MVC project's aim is to create a layer on top Google Web Toolkit's widget library capable of implementing RIAs in easier and more guided way based on a Model-View-Controller design pattern for the client part.